# Inserting rows to a UITableView with out changing the position of the previous content

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to insert a row at the beginning of the table but I want to maintain the position of the previous content (similar to the Twitter app when it loads more tweets), at the moment I'm using the following code:

`- (void) insertObject: (id) object
{
    [_objects insertObject: object atIndex: 0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
    [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}`

Comment: I think he will preserve the actual position after an insert.

So if the tableview shows cell 1-5 and he insert a row on position 0. Then the visible rows should be 1-5 and not 0-4.

Comment: That's right, the question is to maintain the current position after inserting rows before the ones that are shown.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what the issue is here. That said, if you literally just want to insert a new row at the top of the table then why can't you just do the following:

```
- (void) insertObject: (id) object
{
    [_objects insertObject: object atIndex: 0]; // Add the new object to the array (position 0)
    [self.tableView reloadData]; // Reload the data in the table
}
```

**NOTE:** This is based on the assumption that when populating the data in your table you iterate through each object in the array in order.